# Reshape the data from three columns to two column

Tags: r, reshape, social-networking, reshape2

I have a data like this :

```
   Response Prompt Prompt.Label Comments
1    Friend    who          si3      3_a
2         1    was       si4_en      3_a
3         1    was      si4_nag      3_a
4    Family    who          si3      3_b
5         1    was      si4_nag      3_b
6         1    was       si4_en      3_b
7     other    who          si3      4_a
8         1    was       si4_sp      4_a
9     other    who          si3      4_b
10        1    was       si4_en      4_b
11   Friend    who          si3      5_a
12        1    was       si4_en      5_a
13   Family    who          si3      5_b
14        1    was       si4_en      5_b
```

```
data<-structure(list(Response = c("Friend", "1", "1", "Family", "1", 
"1", "other", "1", "other", "1", "Friend", "1", "Family", "1"
), Prompt = c("who", "was", "was", "who", "was", "was", "who", 
"was", "who", "was", "who", "was", "who", "was"), Prompt.Label = c("si3", 
"si4_en", "si4_nag", "si3", "si4_nag", "si4_en", "si3", "si4_sp", 
"si3", "si4_en", "si3", "si4_en", "si3", "si4_en"), Comments = c("3_a", 
"3_a", "3_a", "3_b", "3_b", "3_b", "4_a", "4_a", "4_b", "4_b", 
"5_a", "5_a", "5_b", "5_b")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

I am looking to reshape the data to have two columns, including Source, and Target. "Source" should have the values from "Response" when the "Prompt"=="who", and "Target" should be the values of "Prompt.Label" if "Prompt"= "was" for each value of the "Comments" columns. For instance, for the first row, *Friend*  is going for "Source"   , and *si4_en*  is for "Target".

The desire data should be :

```
  Source  Target
1 Friend  si4_en
2 Friend si4_nag
3 Family si4_nag
4 Family  si4_en
5  other  si4_sp
6  other  si4_en
7 Friend  si4_en
8 Family  si4_en
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to get the desired output:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(cumsum(Response!=1)) %>% 
  mutate(Response = ifelse(Response==1, first(Response), Response)) %>% 
  filter(row_number() !=1) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(Response, Target=Prompt.Label)
```

```
  Response Target 
  <chr>    <chr>  
1 Friend   si4_en 
2 Friend   si4_nag
3 Family   si4_nag
4 Family   si4_en 
5 other    si4_sp 
6 other    si4_en 
7 Friend   si4_en 
8 Family   si4_en
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel we can do it with some very simple `tidyverse` functions, as long as we do some basic data wrangling beforehand. This data.frame is not tidy. The `Response` variable is not self-explicable, and needs some contextual clues for understanding.
I feel we may be better off by first tidying it up with `tidyr::fill`.
Then we can do some simple `select/filter`.

```
data %>%
    mutate(Response = na_if(Response, 1)) %>%
    fill(Response) %>%
    filter(Prompt == 'was') %>%
    select(Source = Response, Target = Prompt.Label)

  Source  Target
1 Friend  si4_en
2 Friend si4_nag
3 Family si4_nag
4 Family  si4_en
5  other  si4_sp
6  other  si4_en
7 Friend  si4_en
8 Family  si4_en
```